# print random result in php 2 dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, random

for a simple array I can print a random item with this code:

```
$key = array_rand($arr);
$value = $arr[$key];
```

But I need do it with 2 dimensional array and one condition.

I have an array like this

```
$arr = array ( 'news' => 'text1',
               'news' => 'text2',
               'fun'  => 'text3',
               'news' => 'text4',
               'echo' => 'text5',
               'fun' => 'text6');
```

I want somthing like this algorithm in php

```
if($type == 'news')
   print random($arr($type));
```

So the results are:

> text1 or text2 or text4

or another example:

```
 if($type == 'fun')
       print random($arr($type));
```

> results: text3 or text6

but how can I do it?

Comment: You can't have multiple keys with the same name! A key must be unique!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by  [@rizier123](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3933332/rizier123) :

> You can't have multiple keys with the same name!! Every though about
>   how you identify each value if there would be multiple keys with the
>   same name?!

Your `$arr` keys must be unique, the code below reflects that.

---

```
   /**
     * multidimensional_array_rand()
     * 
     * @param array $array
     * @param integer $limit
     * @return array
     */
    function multidimensional_array_rand( $array, $limit ) {

    uksort( $array, 'callback_rand' );

  return array_slice( $array, 0, $limit, true ); 
}

/**
 * callback_rand()
 * 
 * @return bool
 */
function callback_rand() { 

  return rand() > rand();

}
```

---

i.e.:

```
$arr = array ( 'news1' => 'text1',
               'news2' => 'text2',
               'fun'  => 'text3',
               'news4' => 'text4',
               'echo' => 'text5',
               'fun' => 'text6');

print_r( multidimensional_array_rand( $arr, 1 ) );
```

---

Output:

```
Array
(
    [news4] => text4
)
```

---

Demo:

http://ideone.com/lVJ57a

Comment: You can't have multiple keys with the same name!! Every though about how you identify each value if there would be multiple keys with the same name?!